# Pulling Yahoo Finance data using PYTHON

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am using the following program to pull data from yahoo finance into a text file on the local drive.  The program does successfully pull the data from yahoo finance into a txt file in my computer.

Why do the code come up with 19 "error"'s followed by a successful pull?

If I want to save the data to database server, how should I approach?

```
import urllib.request
import time

stockstoPull = 'AMD', 'BAC', 'MSFT', 'TXN', 'GOOG'

def pullData(stock):
    fileLine = stock + '.txt'
    urltovisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'
with urllib.request.urlopen(urltovisit) as f:
    sourceCode = f.read(100000).decode('utf-8')
splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')

for eachLine in splitSource:
    splitLine = eachLine.split('.')
    if len(splitLine) == 5:
        if 'values' not in eachLine:
            saveFile = open(fileLine,'a')
            linetoWrite = eachLine+'\n'
            saveFile.write(linetoWrite)
    else:
        print('Error')

print('Pulled', stock)
print('...')
time.sleep(.5)

for eachStock in stockstoPull:     
    pullData(eachStock)
```

Comment: can you post the complete stack trace? There are many wrappers built around the yahoo finance api. The one I use quite often is located here: http://goldb.org/ystockquote.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct, I changed only 2 things. The errors are when the splitLine length is less than 6. You can use sqlite as a database.

```
import urllib.request
import time

stockstoPull = 'AMD', 'BAC', 'MSFT', 'TXN', 'GOOG'

def pullData(stock):
    fileLine = stock + '.txt'
    urltovisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'
    with urllib.request.urlopen(urltovisit) as f:
        sourceCode = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')

    for eachLine in splitSource:
        splitLine = eachLine.split(',') # <---(here ',' instead of '.')
        if len(splitLine) == 6: # <----( here, 6 instead of 5 )
            if 'values' not in eachLine:
                saveFile = open(fileLine,'a')
                linetoWrite = eachLine+'\n'
                saveFile.write(linetoWrite)

    print('Pulled', stock)
    print('...')
    time.sleep(.5)

if __name__=="__main__":
    for eachStock in stockstoPull:     
        pullData(eachStock)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can find a [tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html#remote-data-yahoo) for getting "Yahoo Finance Data" with pandas.

Pandas, Python data analysis library, has it's own remote data access option for getting Yahoo Finance data immediately as a dataframe.

P.S. : Be aware of the warning on the top of the page. You need to install a library additionally which is "pandas_datareader". The result of the query comes a pandas dataframe.